# Why my form label is not aligned on the left, regardless what I type in my css file?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to place the form label on the top-left side, but it does not work. I used Bootrstrap for designing and then I tried to change the CSS code by using ID. It doesn't help. Any advice?
Thank you in advance

```css
#labels {
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <label id="labels" for="">Name</label><br>
  <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Name"> <br>
  <label id="labels" for="">Email Address</label><br>
  <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Email"> <br>
  <label id="labels" for="">Enter Phone</label> <br>
  <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="number" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">


</form>
```

Comment: The text-align property is default to left. What else do you want?

Comment: Do you want like this? - https://ibb.co/gvYJfL9

Comment: FYI: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. Use classes instead of IDs, if you want to be able to select multiple elements at the same time for styling purposes. (Or, in a case like this, use the tag name selector to begin with, in combination with the descendant selector if it is necessary to limit this to a specific form or section.)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#labels {
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You might like this code.
You just have to remove `<br>` which means `break`. It gives you a line space.
So, you have to remove it.

Edited :

```css
#labels {
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  

<label id="labels" for="">Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Name"> <br>
  <label id="labels" for="">Email Address</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Email"> <br>
  <label id="labels" for="">Enter Phone</label> 
  <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="number" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it did not work. I need the labels on top (top-left) of the input form, that's why I needed <br>

Comment: @nailzadeh done! without removing `label`